# How to switch left shiftkey to right shiftkey in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am not able to switch left shift key to right shift key in AutoHotkey. I tried this code to switch but it worked perfectly for up, down, left and right arrows but didn't work for shift keys. Here's the code..

```
up::w
down::s
left::a
right::d
freerun::LShift
Numpad8::up

Numpad8::up
Numpad5::down
Numpad4::left
Numpad6::right
RShift::freerun
NumpadAdd::Enter
NumpadEnter::Backspace
```

Comment: why is this tagged with CSS?

Comment: What does ``freerun::`` bind to?  This isn't a valid hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

You must use $ sign, otherwise lshift will fire rshift, which fires lahift. This will go on forever. $ prevents key from firing by send.
    $LShift::RShift
    $RShift::LShift

Answer (score 1):

There are two important modifiers in AutoHotKey: ~ and $

Without these modifiers hotkey is intercepted and processed. It doesn't propagate. however `k::m` replaces `k` with `m`. `k::k` causes infinite loop.

`~k::m` allows k to go through and them prints `m`. Result is `km`
`~k::k` is a fork bomb. It sends `kk` for each `k`

`$k::m` is ignored if `k` came from AHK and fires if `k` came from keyboard.

```
h::k
$k::m
```

would then produce `h` -> `k` and `k` -> `m` replacements.

You need to use `$LShift::RShift` to avoid the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LShift::RShift
RShift::LShift
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$` to prevent an infinite firing loop. Use this:

```
$LShift::RShift
$RShift::LShift
```